# Tasm procedure declaration

Tags: assembly, tasm

What is a difference between these two declarations(not sure if I'm using right word here) of procedures in TASM:

```
procName proc
```

and

```
procName proc near
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a distance (with `NEAR` or `FAR` in the procedure declaration) the default is inferred from the current model.

> For *TINY*, *COMPACT* and *SMALL* models the default distance is `NEAR`. For all other models `FAR` is the default.

This is true only if you use the simplified segmentation directives (e.g. `.CODE`, `.DATA`, `.STACK`) otherwise `NEAR` is always assumed.
You can also specify `NEAR` or `FAR` in the `.MODEL` directive.

You can override the distance of a procedure by specifying `NEAR` or `FAR` in its declaration.

---

Specify the distance of a procedure automates the generation of two instructions: the `ret`s used inside the procedure and the `call`s used to invoke it.

```
proc1 PROC NEAR
   ret                 ;This generates the C3 opcode (near return)
proc1 ENDP

proc2 PROC FAR
   ret                 ;This generates the CB opcode (far return)
proc2 ENDP

call proc1             ;This generates opcode E8 (call near relative direct)
call proc2             ;This generates opcode 9A (call far absolute direct)
```

---

You can always be explicit by using the `retf` and `retn` instructions and using the `call NEAR PTR proc1`, `call FAR PTR proc2` specifiers.

---

When the assembler encounters a call to a procedure declared later in the source code (technically said *forward declared*) it must use multiple passes to resolve the call.
It first assumes it is a near call, when it encounters the declaration of the called procedure and its distance is not near the assembler need another pass to correct its guess and generate a far call instead.

Multiple passes can be enabled with the `/m` switch, otherwise in such situations you will encounter the error

> forward reference needs override.

---

I was unable to find a PDF version of the TASM 5 manual online, the only source is [this scanned version of the manual](http://www.mif.vu.lt/~julius/Tools/asm/Borland%20Turbo%20Assembler%205.0%20User's%20Guide.pdf).
Chapter 10 (at page 128 of the pdf, 115 of the printed copy) is dedicated to the procedures declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the book [Borland Turbo Assembler User's Guide](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf), page 125 of the PDF (116 on footer) : when **`procName proc`** does not specify the distance (near or far) then this is determined by the model. If the distance is specified (**`procName proc near`**), then the `call` and the `ret` will behave accordingly.

The models are on page 92 of the PDF (83 on footer) :

```
 MODEL            CODE            DATA
---------------------------------------
 tiny             near            near
 small            near            near
 medium           far             near
 large            far             FAR
```